# How to override target="_blank" behavior

Tags: javascript, jquery, href

I have created a simple custom Google Map that has links on the markers. The issue is that all the links have a `target="_blank"` so they open on a new tab. I need the links to open on the same window/tab. I tried this code `$('iframe a[target="_blank"]').removeAttr('target');` but it seems like the Google API re-inserts `target="_blank"` after the page is loaded. Is there a way to prevent to disable `target="_blank"` for that iframe? Thanks!

Comment: Can you manually set the target when you're creating the link?

Comment: What does this give you? `console.log($('iframe a').length)`

Comment: I think the iframe loads an external source? The problem is the so called same origin policy and you can't bind the javascript to the elements within that iframe.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `event.preventDefault()` to stop the browser automatically following the link (and thus opening a new tab), but i'm not sure how well this will work overriding events within iframes

```
<a href="https://google.com" target="_blank">click me</a>
```

```
$('a').click(function(event) {

  // stop the browser automatically opening a new tab
  event.preventDefault();

  // do whatever you want with the url
  window.location = event.target.href

});
```